# Automated build version and release of a WAR using Maven

Tags: java, maven, automation

In my project to we have a pre-made war file supplied from a vendor. We do not have access to source code; just the compiled binary. We can make modifications to war file by updating the configurations and packaging it back to war file and deploy.  I usually do the following:

1. Run a batch script to generate a zip file
2. Extract a war file
3. Add the zip from step 1 to a folder in classes directory of the extracted war file from step 2
4. Packed the updated directory structure back to a war file
5. Save the war file to a version control system like SVN
6. Deploy the war file to Tomcat/weblogic from SVN

How can I automate this using maven?

Comment: This question is different form the identified duplicate [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085347/automate-custom-war-files-using-maven) because this asks for the overall build and release process and how to link various processes. The other question only talks about the war overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085347/automate-custom-war-files-using-maven/26089485#26089485) regarding overlaying WARs. As for the SVN bits, you should probably keep your produced artifacts in a Maven repo instead (setting the versions correctly), and keep only the sources in SVN. Still, what you explained is probably also doable using the [SCM plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkin-mojo.html).
You can use the [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create a zip, and [Antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to move files around.

Comment: We want to keep a version of the artifacts in SVN because there is an existing qualification process which mandates this.

Comment: As mentioned, use the SCM plugin to do that. Upfated the answer to point out other relevant plugins.